# Reading information from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, integration

I am a beginner in iOS. I am trying to create an app and referred a lot of posts in the stackoverflow and some other sites and i used the following code to access the Facebook account.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

} else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }
    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    }];
}
```

After that in a function i used the following code to access the Facebook details of the user.

```
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             _FirstName.text = user.first_name;
             regisrationdetails.fbid = user.id;
             _LastName.text=user.last_name;
             _EmailAddress.text=user.email;
             NSArray *locationarray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:user.location,nil];
             _City.text=[locationarray objectAtIndex:1];
             NSLog(@"%@",user.first_name);

         }
     }];
```

No error is being shown but i can't get the information from Facebook the the text fields.If anyone good at this knows how to access the information then please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)getMeButtonTapped:(id)sender {
if(!_accountStore)
    _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                       options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"571438296262222", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]}
                                    completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                        if(granted){
                                            NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];
                                            _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                                            NSLog(@"Success");

                                            [self me];
                                        }else{
                                            // ouch
                                            NSLog(@"Fail");
                                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                        }
                                    }];
}

- (void)me
{
NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                    URL:meurl
                                             parameters:nil];

merequest.account = _facebookAccount;

[merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", meDataString);

}];}
```

Use this hope this helps you, also add social framework as well as Accounts Framework

Comment: What is _accountStore...??

Comment: Where your accounts information are stored i.e  ACAccountStore

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
- (void)fetchFacebookUserInfo {

    if ( FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                           id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                                           NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSString *name = user.name;
            NSString *userName = user.username;
            NSString *firstName = user.first_name;
            NSString *lastName = user.last_name;
            NSString *email1 = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
            NSString *birthday1 = user.birthday;
            NSString *locale = [user objectForKey:@"locale"];
            NSString *location = [user.location objectForKey:@"name"];

      }

  }];
 }
```